# Out-of-sample vs. test set

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, sample, validation, out-of-sample

Someone asked me if I did out-of-time testing (which I assume is just out-of-sample testing but with a timeline element).  But if I have a test set, is that not essentially the same as  out-of-sample testing?

**Doing an extra out-of-sample testing would basically equal to getting an additional test set  and applying my classifier to that again, wouldn't it?**

Please explain if and how my interpretation is wrong.

*PS: If relevant to your answer, you can assume that approximately 60% was used as training set, 20% as validation set and the last 20 as test set.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out-of-time test means that your test set can't go back in time with respect to the training/validation sets. I.e. training should be earlier in time than testing. So it is not necessarily the same as out-of-sample, which can contain any observations, not used in training.
I think you would not need an extra test set if your current test set obeys the time order.

Comment: Yes, I make sure to obey the time order. So having a test set (that obeys the time order) is out-of-time testing.  Makes sense.  I understand the difference with out-of-sample now.  Thank you @inzl .